# Divide array into two arrays odd and even

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, undefined

This is the code but it returns in unidentified . It should return two arrays where the first one is a set of odd numbers in the original array and the second is odd

```js
function evenAndOdd(array) {
    let odd = [];
    let even = [];
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] % 2 === 0) {
            even.push(array[i]);
        } else {
            odd.push(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return even,odd;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it returns in unidentified"? A JS function can only return one value.

Comment: Probably best to understand about scope [in this case, of the arrays you define in the function] and to decide how you want the information returned - for example perhaps as an array of two arrays, or using arrays that already have been created outside the function itself or....?

Comment: Note you cannot return two separate values, you can return them in object or an array but not separately, eg `return [even,odd];`

Comment: I think it should return `odd`. JavaScript is not Python, and `,` is an [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). What you could return though is `[even,odd]`, and then destructure it later.

Answer (score 1):

adding curly braces around your return values converts them into accessible objects

```js
function evenAndOdd(array) {
    let odd = [];
    let even = [];
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] % 2 === 0) {
            even.push(array[i]);
        } else {
            odd.push(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return {even,odd};
}


console.log(evenAndOdd([1,2,3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

- You have to pass a valid number array.
- and all I have done is just created an object with odd and even values array and return it because your code was only returning odd numbers.

```js
function evenAndOdd(array) {
  let odd = [];
  let even = [];
  let length = array.length
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (array[i] % 2 === 0) {
      even.push(array[i]);
    } else {
      odd.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  return {
    odd,
    even
  };
}

console.log(evenAndOdd([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
```

Comment: You can shortcut that into `return {even, odd};`.

Answer (score 0):

You cant return two separate values from the same function. Instead, you can return a new array containing both of the other arrays.

```js
function evenAndOdd(array){
  let odd = [];
  let even = [];
  for (i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    if (array[i] %2===0){
      even.push(array[i]);
    }else{
      odd.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  return [even,odd];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're returning two or more variables, you can return them inside an array such as:

```js
function evenAndOdd(array) {
  let odd = [];
  let even = [];
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] % 2 === 0) {
      even.push(array[i]);
    } else {
      odd.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  return [even, odd];
}

console.log(evenAndOdd([1,2,3,4,5,6]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function evenAndOdd(array) {
    let odd = [];
    let even = [];
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] % 2 === 0) {
            even.push(array[i]);
        } else {
            odd.push(array[i]);
        }
    }

    return [even, odd];
}

var [even, odd] = evenAndOdd([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
console.log("Even " + even)
console.log("Odd " + odd)
```

Answer (score 0):

`arr[i] & 1 === 0` is more elegant and should run more quickly than `arr[i] % 2 === 0` if you're working with a large array